# Kostant's $G$-invariant part in the sym power ring of adjoint representation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, geometric-representation-theory

Let $g$ be a Lie algebra, say $sl_n(\mathbb C)$. It is considered as the adjoint representation of $G=SL_n(\mathbb C)$.

A famous theorem of Kostant from "*Lie Group Representations on Polynomial Rings*" states that $$S=I\otimes H,$$
where $S( g)=\oplus_{m=0}^\infty \vee^m {g}$ is a graded algebra of the symmetric powers of  the adjoint representation $g$, 
$H$ is $G$-harmonic part, and $I$ is $G$-invariant part.

I would like to see a formula for $I$, or the (degree of) generators of $I$. Is it true $I=\prod_{i=2}^n (1-q^{i})^{-1}$?

$q$ is the symbol for recording the grading.

Comment: Concerning the degrees here (for any simple Lie type), there is a convenient table in section 3.7 of my 1990 text on reflection groups.   (I used $n$ there for the rank, which is $n-1$ for your example.)  Keep in mind that Chevalley's computation of invariants works for any finite group generated by reflections, not just a Weyl group.  Like Francois, I can't make sense of your $I=\dots$ formula; but see my Theorem 3.13 for the well-known Poincare polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

As Kostant himself says there, p. 330 (with $\mathfrak g$ complex reductive, $G$ the adjoint group, $J$ for your $I$):

> Here the structure of $I$ is given by a theorem of Chevalley. This asserts that $I$ is a polynomial ring in $l$ (the rank of $\mathfrak g$) homogeneous generators $u_i$, $i = 1,2,\cdots, l$ with $\deg u_i= m_i+ 1$ where the $m_i$ are the exponents of $\mathfrak g$.

These exponents and their computation are discussed in his previous paper [*The principal three-dimensional subgroup...*](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=114875), e.g. for $sl_n$ they are $1,2,\cdots,n-1$. This is covered in Bourbaki, Lie Groups, [Chap. VIII, §8, Thm 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=oCO0xOzNLhAC&pg=PA145) ((i): restriction $\mathrm S(\mathfrak g)\to\mathrm S(\mathfrak h)$ induces an isomorphism $I\to\mathrm S(\mathfrak h)^W$).

I am not sure how to interpret your proposed "formula for" $I$. It looks like a [Poincaré series](https://books.google.com/books?id=4NpGP9BbdygC&pg=PA103) whereas Kostant gives the [Poincaré polynomial](https://books.google.com/books?id=9qdwgNmjLEMC&pg=PA64) of $G$ as $p_G(t)=\prod_{j=1}^l(1+t^{2m_j+1})$, after Hopf.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstood something, in the case of $sl_n$ the Lie algebra is that of $n\times n$ matrices $M$ with zero trace. The invariants are given by traces of powers of $M$. Here, the algebra of invariants is generated by ${\rm tr}(M^k)$ for $k=2,\ldots,n$. These generators are algebraically independent, so your formula for the Cayley-Sylvester-Hilbert series of $I$, is I believe correct.